# Can't create table PHP MySQL with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have the next problem: when I try to make CREATE TABLE php-script with foreign key, I get this error: "Can't create table 'apartments.customers' (errno: 150)".
This is script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('apartments', $link) or die(mysql_error());
$d="CREATE TABLE Customers(
 id_customer int(50) not null primary key,
 name char(50) not null,
 id_apart int(50) not null,
 foreign key(id_apart) references Apartments(id_apart)
);";
mysql_query($d) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Сделано.";mysql_close($link);
?>
```

And this is a script of first table, which works perfectly!

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('apartments', $link) or die(mysql_error());
$s="CREATE TABLE Apartmets (id_apart int(50) not null primary key, price int(50) not null, area int(50) not null);";
mysql_query($s) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Сделано.";mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Please, help me! What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it's a typo `Apartmets` => `references Apartments(id_apart)`

Comment: ...totally off-topic.

Comment: Apart from the typo that Fred pointed out, you're using `mysql_*` which is deprecated and `int(50)` makes no sense because `50` is how many digits will be displayed. `int` can store only 9 digits (10, if you calculate the minus sign), so `int(50)` is absolutely pointless. Please consider using newer, proven, tested approach to dealing with PHP. What you're using is really outdated.

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Thank you very much! I'm a student and I learn PHP/MySQL by tutorial, that I've got from my teacher...

Comment: @Mjh Thank you very much!